# Axios CORS issue Consuming API

Tags: vue.js, cors, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm having a problem with cors. I don't have access to the server, providing the 3rd party API, but it does use the right headers to provide me access. I know, because a native XHR request works, with just putting the authorization and client_id headers, which are required from the api to be set.

I couldn't anyhow make it work with Axios, spent 3 days on this. I'll be really glad if someone helps me out! Please look at the code I made some comments there.

This is the native XHR request, which works:

```
var data = "{\"birthday\":\"1981-07-07\",\"email\":\"asdiiii@mail.com\",\"phone\":\"1234578901\"}";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.response);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "cross-url/api/detail");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "fake");
xhr.setRequestHeader("client_id", "fake");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.send(data);
```

Axios code, which doesn't work:

```
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain'

      const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'cross-url',
        // crossdomain:true, // this doesn't help
        //mode:'cors', // this doesn't help too
        /*
        headers: {
          'content-type':'application/json',
          'client_id':'client_id_here',
          'access-control-allow-origin':'*', // if I put this I get an error it's denied by 'access-control-allow-headers'
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 
        'Accept,Origin,Authorization,client_id,content-type,x-requested-with', // If I put this I get still an error that the header doesn't allow origin'
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        },
        */
        headers: { 
            'client_id':'fake',
        },
        transformRequest: [
          (data,headers) => {
            delete headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN']
            console.log(data)
    //                return JSON.stringify(data) // this also doesn't work'
            return data
          },
        ],  
      });

      instance.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = 'fake';

      const postData3 = {
        email:'fake',
        phone:'123123123',
        birthday:'1981-07-07',

      }
      instance.post('/api/detail', postData3).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      }).catch((e) => { 
      console.log(e)
        console.log(e.request)
      })
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are _response_ headers, and do not go on the request.

Comment: If I don't put any headers, I get that 'access-control-allow-origin' is missing. If I put 'access-control-allow-origin' I get 'access-control-allow-headers' doesn't allow 'access-control-allow-origin', I've put it in comments. How can I put 'access-control-*' in the response headers?

Comment: You need to make _the server_ send CORS headers.  Learn about CORS.

Answer (score 0):

The server determines what headers are allowed, what methods are allowed, and what hosts are allowed.

access-control-allow-xxx are a server-to-client headers, and for all practical purposes, no servers will accept them.

## Concerning CORS

Remove your access-control.xxx headers and then look at the response.  If denied, the server will let you know why.

If you do not have access to the server, and your host, method, and/or client-headers are denied, all you can do is use a proxy (forward your calls from the browser to an intermediate server).  You will need access to some server for that however.

Comment: If I don't put any headers, I get that 'access-control-allow-origin' is missing. If I put 'access-control-allow-origin' I get 'access-control-allow-headers' doesn't allow 'access-control-allow-origin', I've put it in comments up in the axios code I gave. I don't seem to understand why axios doesn't work even if I put headers, while the native XHR works even without putting them :(